# Why is my Auth.User given me null as value ? What is the relationship between sessions and PhpUnit ?

Tags: unit-testing, session, cakephp, testing, phpunit

2) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest::testLogin
Session content for "Auth.User" differs.
null does not match expected type "array".

This is the code that I have

```
function testLogin()
{
    $this->enableCsrfToken();
    $this->enableSecurityToken();

    $this->post('/users/login', [
        'username' => 'username@test.test',
        'password' => 'password'
    ]);

    $expected = [
        'username' => 'username@test.test',
        'password' => 'password'
    ];
    $this->assertSession($expected, 'Auth.User');

    $expected = [
        'controller' => 'Index',
        'action' => 'index'
    ];
    $this->assertRedirect($expected);
}
```

I am using cakephp3.0 and IntegrationTestCase. It seems to me like I can't login ? Why is there a null value for Auth.User ? What is the relationship between PhpUnit and sessions ? I don't get this. 
What am I doing wrong ? 
Isn't the 'Auth.User' what is written in the session ? I am a beginner with testing.